# Send notifications when A user receivers a message.(no Cloud Functions)

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know other options to send users notifications when they receive a message. I am using Firestore to store the messages under their UID.I already tried cloud functions. Any other way to send notifications?

Comment: You mean you are asking for alternatives of firebase push notification?

Comment: " when they receive a message" - 'when the document changes? or something else

Comment: @Mohitpatel yup.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul yes

Answer (score 0):

Try one signal. It is free and easy to use. And the best part is it is used widely by developers.